# Approximating the logarithm of sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation

I  would like to approximate
$$
\ln(\sum_{k=0}^n(n-2k)^p)
$$
Here $p\geq 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the upper limit should be $n/2$ to avoid powers of negative numbers (particularly problematic if $p$ isn't an odd integer).  I would convert to an integral:  $\sum_{k=0}^n(n-2k)^p \approx \int_{k=0}^{n/2}(n-2k)^p\;dk$ which yields to the substitution $u=n-2k$.

Comment: Where did the logarithm go?

Comment: @SauravTomar:  Once the integral is evaluated, one can take the log.